# lspci machine-readable format (-vmm) does not show a kernel Module/Driver line

Tags: utilities, pci

I briefly read the manual of lspci, where I found out that there is a machine-readable format lspci output using "-m" or "-mm" or "-vmm".

I need to print out the device name, the device id and the kernel module driver in use using the machine-readable format.

I tried this command:

```
$ lspci -vmm -v -nn -d 10de:0393
Slot:   01:00.0
Class:  VGA compatible controller [0300]
Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10de]
Device: G73 [GeForce 7300 GT] [0393]
SVendor:    Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [1462]
SDevice:    NX7300GT-TD256EH [0412]
Rev:    a1
```

Compared to this output:

```
$ lspci -nn -v -d 10de:0393
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G73 [GeForce 7300 GT] [10de:0393] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. NX7300GT-TD256EH [1462:0412]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fc000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    I/O ports at cc00 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fe9e0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia_current, nouveau, nvidiafb
```

You can see that the normal (non-machine-readable) format shows the kernel driver/module in use.

How do I get it to show the Driver/Module lines in machine-readable format?

In the manual it says that "Module" and "Driver" lines are optional. Does that mean that I have to compile it from source with some special attributes?

P.S. I know about awk and sed and other workarounds, I'm just curious why it doesn't work.

I use ubuntu 12.10, pciutils version 3.1.9-5ubuntu4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the developer, it seems it was not a bug per se, but at least it's now a feature request of some sort. :)

> > I'm not sure if it's a bug, but I can't print the "Driver" / "Module" lines
> >     using -vmm -v option. It works without it (only -v).
>
> It's a good idea, I will add it.